# AngularJS: What compile function does

Tags: angularjs

i am new in angular js.

just like to know about few line like what they does.

```
app.directive('fancybox', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

      $scope.open_fancybox = function() {

        var el = angular.element(element.html()),

        compiled = $compile(el);

        $.fancybox.open(el);

        compiled($scope);

      };
    }
  };
});
```

below these lines are not clear.

```
var el = angular.element(element.html()),
compiled = $compile(el);
$.fancybox.open(el);
compiled($scope);
```

1) what $compile does and what it return after compile ? 2) when we need to compile scope like compiled($scope);

i have test the if i comment this line compiled($scope); then value is not putting into expression.......why ?

please guide me in detail. thanks

Comment: For details: Go through [this section](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#example) line by line.   and see this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) and read the comments specially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of compile is it compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and return a template function which can be used **to link scope and template together**.

See your last line
       compiled($scope);

Here you are binding $scope with a template that is the functionality of $compile.